# RecipientId get changed by docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I am creating envelope using DocuSign API. While creating envelope I am also passing list of signers and also set my own unique "RecipientId" (GUID) for each signers. But when envelope gets created and checking the list of recipients(signers) and found that recipient id gets changed all time. It is not  "RecipientId" which I am passing.

Can you help me how can we set own "RecipientId" while creating envelope?

-- Create envelope request

```
 { "documents": [{
                    "documentBase64": "<Base64BytesHere>", 
                    "documentId": "1", 
                    "fileExtension": "pdf", 
                    "name": "lite" 
                }], 
    "emailSubject": "test recipient 2", 
    "recipients": { "signers": [ { "email": "xxx.yyy@xxx.com", 
                                    "name": "xxx yyy", 
                                    "recipientId": "1" 
                                    } ]
                  }, 
    "status": "sent" 
 }
```

-- Web hook Response see recipient Id --

```
<DocuSignEnvelopeInformation><EnvelopeStatus>
    <RecipientStatuses>
        <RecipientStatus>
            <Type>Signer</Type>
            <Email>xxx.yyy@abc.com</Email>
            <UserName>xxx yyy</UserName>
            <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
            <Sent>2017-08-29T02:13:33.853</Sent>
            <DeclineReason xsi:nil="true"/>
            <Status>Sent</Status>
            <RecipientIPAddress/>
            <CustomFields/>
            <AccountStatus>Active</AccountStatus>
            <RecipientId>011eac75-f2fa-4f57-94df-5aedaxxxxxxx</RecipientId>
        </RecipientStatus>
    </RecipientStatuses>
....
<DocuSignEnvelopeInformation><EnvelopeStatus>
```

Comment: Can you please share  your request.

Comment: @CodingDawg {
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentBase64": "<Base64BytesHere>",
      "documentId": "1",
      "fileExtension": "pdf",
      "name": "lite"
    }
  ],
  "emailSubject": "test recipient 2",
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "email": "xxx.yyy@xxx.com",
        "name": "xxx yyy",
        "recipientId": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": "sent"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a unique recipientId for each recipient while creating an envelope.

Here is a sample [CreateEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) request

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes
```

Json Payload.

```
{
 "emailSubject": "Please sign the agreement",
 "status": "sent",
 "recipients": {
     "signers": [
         {
             "email": "janedoe@acme.com",
             "name": "jane doe",
             "recipientId": 1,
             "routingOrder": 1,
             "tabs": {
                 "signHereTabs": [
                     {
                         "documentId": "1", "pageNumber": "1", "xPosition": "80", "yPosition": "80"
                     }

                 ]
             }
         },
         {
             "email": "johnsmith@acme.com",
             "name": "john smith",
             "recipientId": 2,
             "routingOrder": 2,
             "tabs": {
                 "signHereTabs": [
                     {
                         "documentId": "1", "pageNumber": "1", "xPosition": "80", "yPosition": "180"
                     }

                 ]
             }
         }
     ]
 },
 "documents": [
     {
         "documentId": "1",
         "name": "Contract",
         "fileExtension": "txt",
         "documentBase64": "RG9jIFRXTyBUV08gVFdP"
     }
 ]
}
```

---

Use the [listEnvelopeRecipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list/) api to retrieve the list of recipients in the envelope.

```
{
  "signers": [
    {
        "creationReason": "sender",
        "isBulkRecipient": "false",
        "name": "jane doe",
        "email": "janedoe@acme.com",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "recipientIdGuid": "98d60cc3-5f67-46e4-9fc0-ca6bb519f1c9",
        "requireIdLookup": "false",
        "userId": "585b8733-b1a9-4329-87e7-4f20bcde00c2",
        "routingOrder": "1",
        "status": "sent"
    },
    {
        "creationReason": "sender",
        "isBulkRecipient": "false",
        "name": "john smith",
        "email": "johnsmith@acme.com",
        "recipientId": "2",
        "recipientIdGuid": "726bd54d-89ed-41ba-a751-fdb129894b8b",
        "requireIdLookup": "false",
        "userId": "45abe022-ae12-4816-8c42-fd66d207807a",
        "routingOrder": "2",
        "status": "created"
    }
  ],
"agents": [],
"editors": [],
"intermediaries": [],
"carbonCopies": [],
"certifiedDeliveries": [],
"inPersonSigners": [],
"recipientCount": "2",
"currentRoutingOrder": "1"
}
```

Comment: That is I am also doing.. but recipient id get changed from docusign. When I retrieve recipients list then recipient id get changed to some GUID.

Comment: Looks like the connect response does not contain the recipient Id that is specified during envelope creation. DocuSign also creates an internal recipient Id when creating the envelope. You can use the [listRecipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list/) api to retrieve the map between the recipient id's. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yes that is right.. but i need it when recipient status get changed. but now i am ok, first I will update recipient list when envelope is created. It contains RecipientGuidId and then when status get changed and in webhook request I will use RecipientId as RecipientGuidId. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Another way around this is to use `recipient.customFields`. It's an array of strings:

```js
someEnvelopeSigner.customFields = [yourUUID, somethingElse]
```

In the webhook / event notification, it will come through in `DocuSignEnvelopeInformation.EnvelopeStatus[0].RecipientStatuses[0].RecipientStatus[i].CustomFields` and look something like (in JSONified form)

```js
{
  "CustomFields": [{
    "CustomField": [
      "6e45cb20-3953-11ea-b02d-dedef9da77b9",
      "something else!"
    ]
  }],
}
```